# Parse error for float values

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to get a float value from a log line but logstash mutate filter rounds the value and converts it into integer.

The log line is

```
f413e89e-8c2f-e411-97a5-005056820dbe|0,0033
```

and the configuration file is

```
input {
    file {
        path => "log.txt"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "%{UUID:request_object_id}[/|]%{LOCALNUM:total_time}"]
    }

    mutate {
            gsub => ["total_time", "[,]", "."]
            convert => [ "total_time", "float" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

`LOCALNUM` is a custom pattern and it is

```
(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:[,][0-9]+)?)|(?:[,][0-9]+)))
```

(uses "," instead of "." in floating numbers).

With this configuration, `total_time` is `0` instead of `0.0033`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I found my mistake. I used 2 seperate `mutate` blocks, 1 for `gsub` and the other for `convert` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the logstash source code it does this:

```
convert(event) if @convert
gsub(event) if @gsub
```

So it does the `convert` before the `gsub`.  Try splitting your `mutate` into two different `mutate`s and it will fix your problem.

```
mutate {
        gsub => ["total_time", "[,]", "."]
}
mutate {
        convert => [ "total_time", "float" ]
}
```